# Delphi 7 Ado Dataset not in edit or insert mode

Tags: delphi-7, microsoft-access

Estou fazendo um programinha em Delphi 7 com Access (eu sei que é coisa velha). 
Mas está dando o erro quando tento gravar em uma coisa bem simples.

```
tblPerguntas.Open;
tblPerguntas.Insert;
tblPerguntaspergunta.Value := edtPergunta.Text;
tblPerguntasControle.Value := 0;
tblPerguntasArquivo.value := edtMusica.Text;
tblRespostasResposta.Value := edtCerta.text;
tblPerguntas.Post;
```

Onde estou errando? Lembrando que a tabela `tblPerguntas` com campo `ID` é auto numeração.

Answer (score 1):

como dito anteriormente  o erro é por que a tabela nao esta em modo de edição ou inserção
segue  a alteração no código:

```
//inicio do seu código 
tblPerguntas.Open; 
tblPerguntas.Insert; 
//coloque a tabela em modo de edição 
tblPerguntas.edit; 
tblPerguntaspergunta.Value := edtPergunta.Text; 
tblPerguntasControle.Value := 0; 
tblPerguntasArquivo.value := edtMusica.Text; 
tblRespostasResposta.Value := edtCerta.text; 
tblPerguntas.Post;
```

Answer (score 0):

Como esse erro ocorre quando sua tabela não está em modo de Inserção ou Edição, Verifique o estado da tabela antes de salvar. Veja:

```
// Faltou Definir a forma de Edição / Inclusão para 
// a Tabela tblRespostas
//
tblRespostas.Open;
tblPerguntas.Open;

Try  

    tblRespostas.Insert;
    tblPerguntas.Insert;

    // Importante verificar, pois pode ocorrer algum erro antes
    // da atribuição dos valores aos campos.
    // Ex: Erro em OnOpen, OnNewRecord, OnConnect Etc.
    //
    If ( tblRespostas.State In [ dsInsert, dsEdit ] ) And
      ( tblPerguntas.State In [ dsInsert, dsEdit ] ) Then
    Begin
        tblPerguntaspergunta.Value := edtPergunta.Text;
        tblPerguntasControle.Value := 0;
        tblPerguntasArquivo.value := edtMusica.Text;
        tblRespostasResposta.Value := edtCerta.text;
        tblPerguntas.Post;
        tblRespostas.Post; // Inclua esta tabela tambem
    End;

Finally
   tblRespostas.Close;
   tblPerguntas.Close;
End;
```

Não esqueça de declarar "DB" na cláusula Uses.